# Creating Sorting Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, func

I wanna create a sorting generic Func `Creating Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>` in an extension method :

```
public static Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> GetOrderByFunc<T>(this KeyValuePair<string, SortingType> keyValuePair)
{
    //I expect the following result
    //Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderby = q => q.OrderByDescending(c => c.Name);

    //keyValuePair.Key is name of property in type of T that I should sort T by it
    switch (keyValuePair.Value)
    {
        case SortingType.Ascending:
            // Creating Ascending Sorting Func
            break;

        case SortingType.Descending:
            // Creating Descending Sorting Func
            break;

        default :
            break;
    }
}
```

Could you guide me, how I can do it?

**Edit:**

this sorting also, contains of count of a T's navigation property.
e.g:

```
// keyValuePair.Key equals "User.Count"
// User is a navigation property of T
Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderby = q => q.OrderByDescending(c => c.User.Count);
```

**Edit:**

I changed `GetSelector` as the following, but an exception has occurred in `bodyExpression`.

```
public static Expression GetSelector<T>(string propertyName)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    if (propertyName.Contains("."))
    {
        propertyName = propertyName.Substring(0, propertyName.IndexOf("."));
        Type navigationPropertyCollectionType = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;

        if (navigationPropertyCollectionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
        {                        
            Expression countParameter = Expression.Parameter(navigationPropertyCollectionType, "c");
            MemberExpression countExpression = Expression.Property(countParameter, "Count");
//Exception: Instance property 'Users(ICollection`1)' is not defined for type 'System.Int32'
            var bodyExpression = Expression.Property(countExpression, propertyName, countParameter);
            return Expression.Lambda(bodyExpression, parameter);
        }
    }
    MemberExpression bodyMemberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName));
    return Expression.Lambda(bodyMemberExpression, parameter);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the first thing that we'll need is a method that can get the selector expression that selects out that property value when given the property name.  It will need to build the expression from scratch:

```
public static Tuple<Expression, Type> GetSelector<T>(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression body = parameter;

    foreach (var property in propertyNames)
    {
        body = Expression.Property(body,
            body.Type.GetProperty(property));
    }

    return Tuple.Create(Expression.Lambda(body, parameter) as Expression
        , body.Type);
}
```

Note that since this results in a chain of properties the method also returns the type of the final property, as that wouldn't be a particularly easy bit of information to access from the caller's perspective.

Because we don't know the return type of the property *when calling Selector* so we have no choice but to leave the return type of this method typed to `Expression`.  We can't cast it to an `Expression<Func<T, Something>>`.  We could have it return a `Expression<Func<T, object>>`, and that would work for all properties that select out a reference type, but this wouldn't be able to box value types, so it would throw a runtime exception in those cases.

Now, because we don't know the exact type of that expression we can't call `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` directly.  We need to grab those methods through reflection and use `MakeGenericMethod` so that they can be created using the proper type based on inspection of that property using reflection.

```
public static Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> GetOrderByFunc<T>(
    this Tuple<IEnumerable<string>, SortingType> sortCriteria)
{
    var selector = GetSelector<T>(sortCriteria.Item1);
    Type[] argumentTypes = new[] { typeof(T), selector.Item2 };

    var orderByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
        .First(method => method.Name == "OrderBy"
            && method.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(argumentTypes);
    var orderByDescMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
        .First(method => method.Name == "OrderByDescending"
            && method.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(argumentTypes);

    if (sortCriteria.Item2 == SortingType.Descending)
        return query => (IOrderedQueryable<T>)
            orderByDescMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { query, selector.Item1 });
    else
        return query => (IOrderedQueryable<T>)
            orderByMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { query, selector.Item1 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it dosen't work for sorting navigation properties count. please see Edit section in main question.Could you please guide me how we should do it?

Comment: @Mohammad That's because you're not sorting on a property by it's name.  You'll need to alter the `GetSelector` method to add a `Property` call for each property access that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but do you have a reference link for it, I'm new on Expression.

Comment: @Mohammad What you see in this answer should have enough for that change; you wouldn't need any tools not used in this answer already.  Just take the result of one `Property` call and pass it to another.

Comment: Well, I wanna sort by `Count` property of a navigation property. Should I Just take the result of one Property call and pass it to another?

Comment: Actually I don't know how should I do it :-( else I wrote it myself

Comment: @Mohammad Try taking a stab at it anyway.  That's how you learn.

Comment: Well, How can we pass a property to another ?

Comment: @Mohammad The first parameter of `Expression.Property` is the object that you're getting a property from.  That could be the parameter, or (for example) the result of another property call.

Comment: I changed GetSelector as the following, but an exception has occurred in bodyExpression. Please see the second edit section

Comment: @Mohammad See my edit.  In short, you were trying to handle the exact case of your one example, rather than just handling the general case (which is honestly much easier).  Rather than special casing "Count" in some way, it just allows a chain of property accesses to be provided.  You can even provide an empty array and sort on "itself".  As for why it didn't work, I didn't look too closely, but my first guess at a likely problem is that you need to fix up the other function a tad as well, so that it calls `OrderBy` with the proper generic type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx)

```
    public static Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> GetOrderByFunc<T>(this KeyValuePair<string, SortingType> keyValuePair)
    {

        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> result;

        var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "p1");
        var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(p1, keyValuePair.Key);
        var lambada = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(prop, new ParameterExpression[] {p1});

        //keyValuePair.Key is name of property in type of T that I should sort T by it
        switch (keyValuePair.Value)
        {
            case SortingType.Ascending:
                result = source => source.OrderBy(lambada);
                break;

            case SortingType.Descending:
                result = source => source.OrderByDescending(lambada);
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the return value of the property is a reference type.  Value types wont' be boxed into an object using this code.

Comment: Ouch, did not notice that when I ran my test. How do you fix that issue?

Comment: Been working on that for a while.  It complicates the problem.  You need to use reflection to call `OrderBy` so that you can pass a `Type` object as the generic argument.  Almost done.

Comment: I finished it up; see my answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the resopnse, please see Edit section in main question